# How can I access AIML predicates while using aiml-high in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot, aiml

I am building a chatbot in Node.js and have been using aiml-high. I am trying to access the predicates of the AIML so that I can store them in variables which I will use later on. I know that in Python there is a way to get the predicates like so:

```
name = kernel.getPredicate("name", sessionId)
```

So, here is my question in more detail. Below is a category from my AIML file.

```
<category>
    <pattern>DO YOU SPEAK <set name="language">*</set></pattern>
    <condition name="language">
      <li value="english">Yes. I do speak <get name="language"/>.</li>
      <li value="English">Yes. I do speak <get name="language"/>.</li>
      <li>Sorry. I don't speak <get name="language"/>. Maybe one day I will learn though.</li>
    </condition>
  </category>
```

If the user says "Do you speak French", the language, which in this case is "French", is stored here:

```
<set name="language:>*</set>
```

Now, the language is remembered and can respond accordingly.

```
<li>Sorry. I don't speak <get name="language"/>. Maybe one day I will learn though.</li>
```

...replacing the `<get name="language"/>` with the language that the user had input. I would like to access that language predicate in my JavaScript so I can use it later. So, I was wondering if anyone has built a chatbot in Node.js and would have insight as to how I would save these predicates.

Answer (score 0):

So, since posting this question I have continued to look through the code for the aiml-high node package. I ended up finding out where the user generated variables are stored and added two new methods to aiml-high.js in the aiml-high node package.

The first method I added is one that returns all of the stored variables:

```
this.getStoredVariables = function() {
  return storedVariableValues;
}
```

This next method allows you to single out which stored variable that you want returned instead of the entire object.

```
this.getSpecificStoredVariable = function(v) {
  return storedVariableValues[v];
}
```

So, even though these two methods are simple and most developers would be able to do what I did by just looking through the aiml-high code itself, I hope that someone looking for a similar answer in the future comes across this answer so they don't have to look through the code themselves.

Also, I added a third method to get the bot's attributes.

```
this.getAttributes = function() {
   return botAttributes;
}
```